# Privileges Based On Custom Field

Tags: account, account-teams, access, privileges

On accounts, we have custom fields for Sales Rep, and Secondary Sales Rep. How can we restrict access to read/write an account ONLY to users who match the strings in these fields?

Are there any ways that are not a one time thing, but will be organic as new users/accounts are added over time?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the OWD settings of Account.

If Account is Private or Public Read only, then you can share those records to those Reps for read/write access through share rules.

If you have OWD is Public Read/Write then:

you should use validation rule (otherwise by trigger) to restrict users to read/write an account.